# Convert column values to percentages

Tags: r, dataframe, format

I am reading in multiple Excel files into lists using `read.xlsx` from the `openxlsx` package.  I append the lists with `rbind` and perform some data manipulation.

What I need to do is convert the values in columns 18 and 19 to percentages (currently the values show as .90, .85, etc. but I can also force the user to enter as 90, 85, etc. I need to 90%, 85%). I have tried to do this inside the data.frame and also using `createStyle`. So far, nothing has worked and will either corrupt my data or simply do nothing.

Here is what I have tried...

**openxlsx Style**

```
# Create percent style
pct = createStyle(numFmt = "0%")
# Apply style
addStyle(wb, sheet = "filename", style = pct, cols = 18, rows = 102, gridExpand = TRUE)
```

**str_replace**

```
allData <- str_replace(allData$'Content', pattern = "%", "")
allData$'Content' <- as.numeric(allData)/100
```

**sapply** (even just trying to convert data type to numeric didn't work. It was still set to General

```
allData[, c(18)] <- sapply(allData[, c(18)], as.numeric)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to go from `.90, .85` to `90, 85` but are *dividing* by `100`.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: @Rui Barradas, for the str_replace implementation, I was testing when the values were whole numbers. Like I said, I can have the user enter decimal or whole numbers. Either way, the implementation wasn't working (regardless if I multipled by 100 or divided).

Comment: @Sotos, I've added a sample data set

Comment: Can you show us the output of `str(allData)` ?

Comment: @nadizan, please see edit above

Comment: How about this? `allData$'Post Processing Tumor Content' <- as.numeric(allData$'Post Processing Tumor Content')/100`

Comment: @nadizan, thanks but this does not work. The values are converted to decimal but still in General format. Otherwise, the file is created just fine but returns: `Warning message:
In eval(ei, envir) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: Use `dput(allData[1:10,])` and post a few rows of your data.

Comment: @nadizan, see EDIT 2 please. Thanks

Comment: I don't see any problem of this, I assume you have strings, that are converted to numeric values, hence get the value "NA" when you have the string "N/A" or any other string. For next time, always use `dput`, and post the minimal part of your data that you can reproduce the error with. It is also a good practise for yourself so you can more easily identify errors. :)

Comment: @nadizan, I should have been more clear. I want the output to be "90%", not .90. The N/A are input by users when the percentage is not known or does not apply.

Comment: Well as I said, be more clear. `paste0(100*as.numeric(allData$'Post Processing Tumor Content'),"%")`

Comment: @nadizan, thanks but that does not work. Values are still whole numbers with no percent sign.

Comment: Sorry, I'm done. Good luck.

Comment: lol, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out sometime ago but forgot to post the answer. For those who are interested...

```
# Create a percent style
pct = createStyle(numFmt = "0%")

# Add percent style
addStyle(wb, sheet = "my_filename", style = pct, cols = c(18, 19), rows = 2:(nrow(allData)+1), gridExpand = TRUE)
```